# Ubuntu 20.04: How can I encrypt the other hard drives on my system with the same key as my primary disk?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. I opted to encrypt my primary hard disk, but I still have about 4 other disks on my system that I wish to encrypt. How can I encrypt the other drives on my system with the same key as the primary one and be able to unlock them all at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encrypt your hard drives using Disks utility which is already installed in Ubuntu 20.04.

To be able to encrypt your hard disk you need to do the following:

1. If you have any data, make backup and **delete the partition**
2. Click on **+ Create partition in unallocated space**
3. Next
4. Choose **Internal disk for use with Linux Systems only (ext4)** && **Password protect volume (LUKS)**
5. Next, write your password
6. Click on **Additional partition options** --> **Edit Encryption Options**
7. **Disable User Session Defaults** --> **Enable Unlock at System Startup**

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Comment: What would the process look like if one were to later erase the system drive and reinstall the OS?  Is it simply a matter of using Disks GUI to enter in the password (from when you set it up) so it knows how to read and mount the second drive?

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04 this only seems to work if the root encryption key is the same as the non-root keys. Otherwise if the non-root keys are the same but differ from the root key, you will be prompted once per LUKS encrypted drive.